# PFObject does not have a member named 'saveInBackground' in Xcode 6.0.1, Yosemite GM3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

Parse is acting very strangely in Yosemite, saveInBackground claims to not be a member of PFObject.

```
var score = PFObject(className: "score")
    score.setObject("Mo", forKey: "name")
    score.setObject(1, forKey: "scoreCount")
    score.saveInBackground()
```

Clearly this should work, perhaps it's an issue with Xcode 6.0.1 or Yosemite GM3 (Or a combination). To be clear, using saveInBackgroundWithBlock works fine.

Has anyone else experienced this or a similarly weird bug?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `saveInBackground` method is declared in the header to return a `BFTask *` object, which is part of the Bolts framework. Make sure your project is linking the Bolts framework, and then add

```
#import <Bolts/Bolts.h>
```

to your bridging header.

This solved a few "missing" APIs in Swift for me (this one, as well as `PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions` mentioned here: [Why does my PFAnalytics not have trackAppOpeneWithLaunchOptions function? (IOS SWIFT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26503914/why-does-my-pfanalytics-not-have-trackappopenewithlaunchoptions-function-ios-s)

Comment: In my bridging header i now have:  #import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <Bolts/Bolts.h> however I get bolts/bolts.h file not found even thought the framework is important just lite the parse framework.

Answer (score 11):

If you don't want to mess around with the Parse framework files, you should replace:

```
score.saveInBackground()
```

with:

```
score.saveInBackgroundWithTarget(nil, selector: nil)
```

Answer (score 3):

**No need for bridging headers since release 1.0**. To fix the issue, just add, `import Bolts` at the top of your class, below `import Parse`:

```
import Parse
import Bolts
```

With the added import statement, `saveInBackground()` should work as is.

Answer (score 1):

ok, got it, in the parse,framework open up headers, go to `PFObject.h` and open it, navigate to where it says `@name Saving Objects` and write down this:

```
(void)saveInBackground;
```

run the app or close and open again Xcode and try to write down again the code and `saveInBackground` should be now an `PFobject` of your score.

Comment: This fixes the issue. But does anyone know why this wasn't in PFObject.h?

Comment: this is a dangerous answer and it might cause issues in the future, please check http://stackoverflow.com/a/26520728/2589276

Answer (score 0):

this work

testObject.saveEventually()