# Why does my PFAnalytics not have trackAppOpeneWithLaunchOptions function? (IOS SWIFT)

Tags: swift, parse-platform

Error message:

```
    'PFAnalytics.Type' does not have a member named 'trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions'
```

All other similar functions work, e.g. trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptionsInBackground. It looks like that it just simply disappears from the list of available functions.

But in my PFAnalytics.h header file, `trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions` is clearly listed as shown below:

```
    + (BFTask *)trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions;
```

What might have been wrong? Please help! I am using `swift`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try

```
PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptionsInBackground(launchOptions, block: nil)
```

instead of

```
PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions()
```

Comment: This is actually a bad idea because PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptionsInBackground is a completely different method meant for the different purpose of tracking background launches.

Comment: It is the same. More info here: https://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFAnalytics.html#//api/name/trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptionsInBackground:block: . The only thing block does is: "The block to execute on server response." So if you set block to nil, it is basically the same.

Comment: Below answer is correct if you want to code like Objective - C. just  #import <Bolts/Bolts.h> in BridgingHeader.h after you have found methods which is not found.

Answer (score 35):

The method is declared to return a `BFTask *` object, which is part of the Bolts framework. Make sure your project is linking the Bolts framework, and then add

```
#import <Bolts/Bolts.h>
```

to your bridging header.

This solved a few "missing" APIs in Swift for me (this one, as well as `PFObject.saveInBackground` mentioned here: [PFObject does not have a member named 'saveInBackground' in Xcode 6.0.1, Yosemite GM3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26411534/pfobject-does-not-have-a-member-named-saveinbackground-in-xcode-6-0-1-yosemit?lq=1)

Answer (score 7):

**No need for bridging headers since release 1.0**. To fix the issue, just add, `import Bolts` at the top of your `AppDelegate` as such:

```
import UIKit

import Parse
import Bolts

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate
{ 
...
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer in my opinion. Thanks!