# fatal error with message post using parse

Tags: swift, parse-platform, xcode6, pfobject

So I am new to using Parse and having some issues with posting a message through the back-end. I am able to set up a user account but when I try to submit the post I am getting an error that says..."fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" ...?

Here is my code:

```
class ComposeViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var travelTextView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet var charRemainingLabel: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()




        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func sendPost(sender: AnyObject) {

        var travelPost:PFObject = PFObject(className: "travelposts")
        travelPost["content"] = travelTextView.text
        travelPost["poster"] = PFUser.currentUser()

        travelPost.saveInBackgroundWithTarget(nil, selector: nil)

        self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)

    }
```

Comment: Hour selector cannot be nil. If not use saveInBackground

Answer (score 0):

you cannot pass nil for selector.

```
travelPost.saveInBackgroundWithTarget(nil, selector: nil);
```

do this to just save the object.

```
travelPost.saveInBackground();
```

But you want to get notified when the object is saved use

Comment: travelPost.saveInBackground is giving me an error that says...'PFObject' does not have a member named 'saveInBackground'

Comment: Are you importing Parse.h file ? . Because PFOjbect does have that method. Here is the doc ref. https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#objects/iOS

Comment: yes I have imported the parse.h file...here are some comments/issues I have read about .saveInBackground methods...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26411534/pfobject-does-not-have-a-member-named-saveinbackground-in-xcode-6-0-1-yosemit

Comment: oh, I see the error now. Did you try this .saveEventually()